# Odd rep cap behavior?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Noticed a bit of strange behavior around the rep cap yesterday. I had an answer to a hot network question that got a bunch of upvotes, so I hit the cap [+200], then some more upvotes [still +200], then someone retracted their upvote [+190] (no idea if this was one of the votes from before or after I hit the cap, but that might be related to the cause of the bug), then some further upvotes [still +190].

Is the rep cap intended to be on net change, or on positive contribution? I guess it might make sense to have down-votes lower the cap, but a retracted upvote seems like it shouldn't.

I'm not too fussed about the 10 rep, but it would be a bit unfortunate if this disqualified the day from counting toward things like Epic (not that I'm ever likely to be Epic, but it's the principle!).

[image: rep changes from yesterday]

Comment: I thought that case was suppose to get sorted these days. That display may be cached and slow to update. You can check it at http://physics.stackexchange.com/reputation . Scroll to the bottom.

Comment: @dmckee Ah, makes sense. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Kyle - ''... retracted the upvote ...'' ! How? Don't votes get locked after sometime ? (Or is it some punishment that the site has only inflicted on me?)

Comment: @New_new_newbie Don't think so, just click upvote again...

Comment: @New_new_newbie you have five minutes to retract a vote, or if the post is edited then you can freely change any vote you cast on it prior to the latest edit. Votes cast more than five minutes ago where the post has not been edited since the vote are indeed locked in.

Comment: @DavidZ - Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 2):

dmckee♦ is correct, this seems to be due to a slow cache. Changes shown at physics.stackexchange.com/reputation show +200.

`2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 (10)
 2    122790 [10]
 2    122790 [0]
 2    122790 [0]
 2    122790 [0]
 2    122790 [0]
 2     74691 [0]
 2    122790 [0]
 16     1659 [0]
 2    122790 [0]
 2    122790 [0]
 2    122790 [0]
-- 2014-07-03 rep +200  = 3384`